# Adding Settings in a Visual Studio Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to add settings to a Visual Studio Code Extension (vscode-powershell)

I edited the `settings.ts` file to add:
A new Interface:

```ts
export interface ICertificateSettings {
    certificateSubject?: string;
}
```

I edited the `ISettings` interface to add my Interface

```ts
export interface ISettings {
    useX86Host?: boolean,
    enableProfileLoading?: boolean,
    scriptAnalysis?: IScriptAnalysisSettings,
    developer?: IDeveloperSettings,
    certificate?: ICertificateSettings
}
```

Then the load function to add my default settings and the return value:

```ts
export function load(myPluginId: string): ISettings {
    let configuration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration(myPluginId);

    let defaultScriptAnalysisSettings = {
        enable: true,
        settingsPath: ""
    };

    let defaultDeveloperSettings = {
        powerShellExePath: undefined,
        bundledModulesPath: "../modules/",
        editorServicesLogLevel: "Normal",
        editorServicesWaitForDebugger: false
    };

    let defaultCertificateSettings = {
        certificateSubject: ""
    };

    return {
        useX86Host: configuration.get<boolean>("useX86Host", false),
        enableProfileLoading: configuration.get<boolean>("enableProfileLoading", false),
        scriptAnalysis: configuration.get<IScriptAnalysisSettings>("scriptAnalysis", defaultScriptAnalysisSettings),
        developer: configuration.get<IDeveloperSettings>("developer", defaultDeveloperSettings),
        certificate: configuration.get<ICertificateSettings>("certificate", defaultCertificateSettings)
    }
}
```

But when I run my extension using the debug panel then launch, I can't see my new "certificate" setting in the PowerShell section.

Do you know what I am missing?

Comment: Any luck? A similar minimum reproducible example worked for me today using v1.36. That's pretty cool you can use a default object. 

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're missing the additions to `package.json`, since that is what actually defines the configuration options.  The Typescript code merely reads them out.  Specifically, you need to add a [`contributes.configuration`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration) section.  For an example, see the corresponding section in [`vscode-powershell/package.json`](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/blob/master/package.json#L446).

Yours would be something like (untested):

```
{
  ...
  "contributes": {
    ...
    "configuration": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "myPluginId",   // whatever it really is
      "properties": {
        "certificate.certificateSubject": {
          "type": ["string", "null"],
          "default": null,
          "description": "..."
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```